# How to find origin of a borrowed word?

Tags: terminology

For example what is the **origin of name Catherine**?

Etymology Dictionary says that:

it's from **French** Catherine, from **Medieval Latin** Katerina, from **Latin** Ecaterina, from **Greek** Aikaterine. The -h- was introduced 16c., probably a folk etymology from Greek katheros "pure." The initial Greek vowel is preserved in Russian form Ekaterina.
As the name of a type of pear, attested from 1640s. Catherine wheel (early 13c.) is named for St. Catherine of Alexandria, legendary virgin martyr from the time of Maximinus who was tortured on a spiked wheel. Her name day is Nov. 25. A popular saint in the Middle Ages, which accounts for the popularity of the given name.

So the origin of this word is 
**Greek**? or **Latin**? or **French**?

**How to find out?**

Comment: You've quoted a text which gives you the origin, and tells you that the earliest form is Greek, but that it has gone through Latin and French. What answer are you looking for beyond that?

Comment: So the oldest language is always the origin?

Comment: The origin of borrowing is Greek.

Comment: If that's what you choose to mean by "origin", then that's what "origin" means. There is no single answer to your question. Any or all of the three languages may be the origin, depending on precisely what you want to use "origin" to mean.

Comment: There are to special terms on this account: **source of borrowing** (language from which the loan word was taken into English) in our case it is French,and **origin** (the language to which the word may be traced) - here it is Greek.

Comment: FWIW, the etymology of Greek _Aikaterinē_ is obscure, per https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Αικατερίνη: (1) the proper name _Ekaterós_ < _ekáteros_ "either"; (2) _katharos_ "clean" (rejected above); (3) the goddess Hecate; (4) _aikia_ "torture"; (5) a Coptic name meaning "the sanctification of your name". Some of these proposals look plausible, some look absurd, and all of them point to confusion.

Comment: @Study.English.Well no living language is any older than any other spoken at the same time. Italian, English, Arabic, Mandarin, Xhosa, Navajo, Finnish, etc are all part of chains of transmission dating back to the dawn of language. All that can be said is that, if a term is borrowed into language A from language B, then language B must have had that term at an earlier date than language A had it. In this case, that means Greek had the name before Latin, which had it before French, which had it before English

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing happens in stages. The English name Catherine is borrowed from French, the French from Latin, the Latin from Greek. From an English point of view the origin is French.

Comment: So unlike with rivers, the *origin* is not where it originates? If one wanted to trace a word back all the way, past it's mere *origin*, what word ought to be used in the sentence "trace the word right back to its ..."?

Comment: The origin is in the garden of Eden (or East Africa, whichever version you prefer). I have not been able to find my way there.

Comment: Follow Starostin to Proto-World. From there you're on your own (-;

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing can also go back and forth. The word "flirt" is used in
French, both as a noun (for the act or for the person) and as a verb
("flirter"). It was clearly borrowed, a few decades ago, from English.

But in English, [it is said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flirting#Etymology) (among other possible origins) to possibly
derives from the French "conter fleurette", borrowed a long time
ago (16th century). I will not get into the etymology of "conter fleurette", since a
quick scan of the web shows many not so compatible views of it.

Answer (score 1):

***Which origin?***

---

If you're looking for which language a word *first emerged*, you'd be looking for the **ultimate origin**.

> So in the case of the name Catherine, we can say that it is **ultimately from** Greek *Aikaterine*.

---

But sometimes we aren't so interested in the ultimate origin so much as an intermediate one, especially when we try to understand how the spelling or pronunciation has changed over time.

There isn't really a specific name for this, but a term I like to use among friends is **[vectoral](https://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/vector_(biology).htm) origin**. Can we determine which language has *transmitted* a particular word to another?

> Catherine was **directly loaned** into English through the French Catherine, hence the identical spelling and similar pronunciation.

---

All of the steps you can find in a dictionary altogether constitute the origin of a word, or at least a speculation thereof.